# How to Focus a TextBox VB.Net

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a text box in my form. When clicking the tray icon the form is shown and on form load I have written the code to focus on the text box. But it's not pointing the text box. 
Let I have 2 forms formB and formC I am calling formC from formB so that I doesn't getting the focus. how to give focus to the second form?
I have find the solution to this problem . we have to overwrite the show method. Let's say formA and formB. Then FormB is in focus now.

```
Private Sub FormB_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
    Me.Timer1.Interval = 2000
End Sub`

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Timer1.Enabled = False
    Dim frmquickListPHD1 As New FormC()
    frmquickListPHD1.Show(CallingForm, CallingControl, Me)
End Sub

   Overloads Sub Show(ByVal f1 As Form, ByVal c As Control, ByVal f2 As Form)
    callingform = f1
    MenuForm = f2
    callingcontrol = c
    Show()
End Sub
Private Sub FormC_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Me.TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub`
```

Comment: Please post the code you have already that is not working

Comment: `me.textbox1.focus()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue may be that the form does not have focus when you open it from the system tray?

Try something like:

```
frmTest.Show
frmTest.Select
```

The in your `Form_Activated` event of `frmTest`

```
textbox1.Select
```

Comment: I have called the form1 from the tray icon form. First the tray icon form loads, through the tray icon form I am calling the form1. This form has a text box and i need to focus on this text box. my code `Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load Dim i As Integer
            For i = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
                If Me.Controls(i).Name Is "TextBox1" Then Me.ActiveControl = Me.Controls(i) End If
            Next End Sub`

Answer (score 1):

use the ActiveControl property of your form in the load event of the form:

```
Me.ActiveControl = Textbox1
```

Alternatively, if you're showing an instance of FormB from FormA on some event then you could use the following code in FormA:

```
Dim FormB1 as new FormB
FormB1.show()
FormB1.ActiveControl = FormB1.Textbox1
```

Don't use focus, from msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus.aspx):

Focus is a low-level method intended primarily for custom control authors. Instead, application programmers should use the Select method or the ActiveControl property for child controls, or the Activate method for forms.

Comment: but it throws me error "Error 2 Property access must assign to the property or use its value."

Answer (score 0):

Set `TabIndex =0`

or

after all loaded in form load
to set `Textbox1.focus()`

Comment: I have already have this code in my form_load. but it's not pointing to the textbox @Senthilkumar

Comment: `Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Me.TextBox1.Focus()
    End Sub`

Comment: your try to set tabindex=0